# No. of solutions of $m^4 = 9n^2 + 72$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

No. of solutions of $m^4 = 9n^2 + 72$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers

My approach:

I figured out that $m$ has to be a multiple of $3$ , so from here I am able to get $4$ solutions $(3,1)$, $(3,-1)$, $(-3,1)$ and $(-3,-1)$.

How can I check for other possible solutions?

Comment: Is one of the *m*s supposed to be *n*?

Comment: Yeah you are right,  apologies for the error made while writing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it should be $m^4 = 9n^2 + 72$ based on what you wrote.

**Hint:** $$m^4 - 9n^2 = (m^2 - 3n)(m^2 + 3n)$$

Comment: Apologies for the mistype, and thanks for the hint , so now I shall write 72 as a product of two of its factors , and then check for each case where I get m and n as integer m^2+3n=12 and m^2-3n=6 would give me my desired solutions , so the answer should turn out to be 4 solutions, right ?

Comment: @Fin27 Yes you are correct!